# Prove the triangle inequality for square matrices (norms)

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

> Prove the triangle inequality $$\|A+B\| \leq \|A\|+\|B\|$$ for any
>   square $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B.$

I'm 100% this is a simple question, but I'm a little bit confused by the question because my teacher didn't specify the norm to work in. Do I need to be in a norm to prove this?

Comment: I'm giving a better than $50\%$ probability to the hypothesis that what was intended was $\displaystyle \|A\| = \sup \left\{ \frac{ \|Ax\|}{\|x\|} : x \in \mathbb R^{n\times1} \right\}$ where the norm on the right side of the equality is the Euclidean norm on vectors or some norm arising from an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, as a fundamental property of a norm is that it must satisfy the triangle inequality.

A norm $N:\mathbb V\rightarrow\mathbb R$ where $\mathbb V$ is any vector space satisfies the following properties:

1) It must always be non negative, i.e, $N(\textbf v) \gt 0 \forall\textbf v \in \mathbb V$ and is zero only when $\textbf v = \textbf 0$

2) It must scale absolutely, i.e, $N(\alpha\textbf v) = |\alpha| N(\textbf v)$

3) It must follow the triangle inequality, i.e, $N(\textbf v_1 + \textbf v_2) \le N(\textbf v_1 ) + N(\textbf v_2)$

The space of matrices is a vector space, and hence wichever norm you take, the property should be satisfied

Comment: Yes... and I could prove this statement for a specific norm (p-norm, Frobenius, etc) But how do I prove this statement **without** knowing the norm? *Can* I do such a thing?

Comment: Yes, for that you would need knowledge of the norm. But you can pick any you like , it will work out for any one of them